# Does Travis ci allow ghc versions larger than 7.8?

Tags: haskell, ghc, travis-ci

I just created a Haskell Travis CI project with this `.travis.yml`:

```
language: haskell
ghc:
  - 7.8
  - 7.10
```

But Travis interprets the second version as `7.1`: https://travis-ci.org/fhaust/dtw/jobs/57648139

The version is only recognized if I enclose it in quotes (though this results in other errors, since 7.10 is not a version available on Travis CI):

```
language: haskell
ghc:
  - 7.8
  - "7.10"
```

Is this a bug?

#### Edit 2015-11-22

There is an open issue for GHC 7.10 on travis-ci: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3785

Comment: Did you every get this working? Does Travis support 7.10 at all? When I try (using quotes) [I get](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/builds/92100003) a "no such version" error.

Comment: Hmm ... yep ... there is a travis configuration file for multiple ghc versions here: https://github.com/hvr/multi-ghc-travis ... but if I remember correct I lost some travis features along the way.

Comment: So the above does not work, correct? You have to go down to C and build the whole Haskell stack from scratch. Right?

Comment: The multi-ghc thing worked. I can’t really remember why I don't use it anymore.

Comment: The link, yes, but not the example in the question, right? `language: haskell` doesn't work (for 7.10) does it?

Comment: If they have not updated travis then no, it does not work.

Comment: So just to be clear "It works if I put marks around the version number" is not correct. right?

Comment: Yes. I was hoping that this would change given some time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a consequence of using YAML files for config: YAML parses `7.10` as the number `7.1`.

The [node.js docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/) on Travis *do* have all the version numbers in quotes:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.12"
  - "0.11"
  - "0.10"
  - "0.8"
  - "0.6"
  - "iojs"
  - "iojs-v1.0.4"
```

Comment: *Does* Travis support 7.10 at all? When I try (using quotes) [I get](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/builds/92100003) a "no such version" error.