# travis haskell builds failing with linking error

Tags: haskell, github, travis-ci

for some time, the [travis builds](https://travis-ci.org/emmanueltouzery/cigale-timesheet/builds/93536873) of my little haskell app are failing with a cryptic link error:

```
$ cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal build && cabal test
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Setup.hs, dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking ./dist/setup/setup ...
/usr/lib/ghc/unix-2.5.1.0/libHSunix-2.5.1.0.a(execvpe.o): In function `pPrPr_disableITimers':
(.text+0x320): multiple definition of `pPrPr_disableITimers'
/home/travis/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.4.1/unix-2.7.1.0/libHSunix-2.7.1.0.a(ghcrts.o):ghcrts.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
The command "cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal build && cabal test" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

The builds work fine on my machine. Is there anything I can tune in my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/emmanueltouzery/cigale-timesheet/blob/master/.travis.yml) file to fix the issue there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first I'm on the legacy travis system, I guess I need to go on the new one. But that one requires much more thorough config I think. Second on the legacy system, ghc 7.10 is not supported: stackoverflow.com/questions/29516932/… I had configured 7.10 but didn't realize that didn't work, and since travis didn't recognize the ghc version, it just put me the oldest, 7.4. So I reverted to 7.8 for now, and the error is now different and more understandable.
So the root cause for weird error was being fallback to the relatively ancient ghc 7.4 due to my misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is usually caused by having multiple versions of a library in your dependency tree, which `cabal configure` allows while `cabal install` will not. I don't see evidence of that in your build log, but it might theoretically be happening. You can try changing `cabal configure` to `cabal install` and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for the hint! I actually tried running the exact same commands that travis runs on my machine, in a sandbox, and it works fine on my machine (or to be exact, it fails with a different error, but I know how to handle that one). That said, I use ghc 7.10 & travis uses 7.4 and I don't understand why. I asked for 7.10 in my travis.yml. About your advice, I'm not sure how could I ask travis to run different commands (eg configure to install for instance).

Comment: I'd recommend following one of these guides: https://github.com/hvr/multi-ghc-travis http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE.html#travis-with-caching

Comment: there are several things. first I'm on the legacy travis system, I guess I need to go on the new one. But that one requires much more thorough config I think. Second on the legacy system, ghc 7.10 is not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516932/does-travis-ci-allow-ghc-versions-larger-than-7-8#comment55387942_29517437 so I reverted to 7.8 for now. I may just give up as it seems it won't be a simple fix. Probably not worth it for an after-work project on which I'm the sole contributor.